# R, Google Ads and Debian - authorization without using a browser

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, debian, authorization, google-ads-api

I am looking for a way to run a simple R script using the "rgoogleads" library to fetch Google Ads data on a debian VM and send to database. Unfortunately, I cannot use the browser that is needed to perform the authorization. Is there a way around?

Comment: You will likely need refresh and access tokens, see https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication I'm not accustomed to Google Ads, but usually the idea with OAuth2 is first to create a small file (the refresh token), that you can use in your app to generate an access token that will in turn be able to access the OAuth2 api. See also https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/oauth2.0_token.html

Comment: What about using .json files like in `gads_auth_configure(path = "~/pathto/token.json")`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a service account instead: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/oauth-service